# Solaris 11 - PAM application

Tags: package-management, solaris, pam, header-file

I'm trying to compile an application which interacts with the PAM system on Solaris 11, however everytime I try compile the code I get

> "fatal error: security/pam_appl.h: No such file or directory"

I know that I'm missing the header files for the pam-dev library, but I'm unsure exactly what package I need to install in order for the required header files to be added to the "/usr/include/" directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pkg search pam_appl.h` should tell you that the package you need to install on Solaris 11 is `system/header`.